# execute c# method with multiple parameters from f#

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

I am new to F#, and I am trying to execute a static C# function that accepts multiple parameters from the F# file/code.

I have a single solution which contains both, C# project as well as F# project.

#### C# project

Code from the C# file:

```
using ...

namespace Factories
{
    public static class FruitFactory
    {
        public static string GiveMe(int count, string fruitname)
        {
            ...
            ...
            return ... (string) ...
        }
    }
}
```

#### F# project

Code from the F# file:

```
open System
open Factories

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let result = FruitFactory.GiveMe 2 "Apples"
    printfn "%s" result
    printfn "Closing Fruit Factory!"
    0
```

From the above piece of code, I am getting the below errors for the code `let result = FruitFactory.GiveMe 2 "Apples"`

Error 1:

```
  Program.fs(6, 37): [FS0001] This expression was expected to have type
    'int * string'    
but here has type
    'int'
```

Error 2:

```
Program.fs(6, 18): [FS0003] This value is not a function and cannot be applied.
```

Comment: This code works perfectly if the C# function accepts only single parameter, for example: if C# function is `... GiveMe(int count) ` and the F# code is `... FruitFactory.GiveMe 2 `, then everything works!

Comment: You can read about functions at [FSharpForFunAndProfit.com](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/defining-functions/). This article explains functions in F# and how to work with them. I recommend to read entire "Thinking functionally" series to understand core principles of F#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# functions are uncurried, so you have to call it as though it takes a tuple, like this: `FruitFactory.GiveMe(2, "Apples")`.

If you really want to create a C# function that can be called with curried arguments from F#, you have process each argument separately. It's not pretty, but it can be done like this:

### C# project

```cs
using Microsoft.FSharp.Core;

public static class FruitFactory
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Curried version takes the first argument and returns a lambda
    /// that takes the second argument and returns the result.
    /// </summary>
    public static FSharpFunc<string, string> GiveMe(int count)
    {
        return FuncConvert.FromFunc(
            (string fruitname) => $"{count} {fruitname}s");
    }
}
```

### F# project

You can then call it the way you want from F#:

```ml
let result = FruitFactory.GiveMe 2 "Apple"
printfn "%s" result
```

Comment: Yes, it works, thank you.
I was hoping to execute the function like `FruitFactory.GiveMe 2 "Apples"`. Is that possible to achieve?

Comment: Thats great! Please go ahead, I am eager to see what you want to demonstrate.

Comment: OK, I've updated my answer to show how it can be done. I don't recommend it, but it is possible.

Comment: Please, in general, don't delete comments. It makes it hard to understand the conversation.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. The missing comment said that I could show how to create a curried function in C#. After writing it, I deleted it because I realized that I wasn't entirely sure how to do it cleanly, but figured it out after that.

Answer (score 1):

Multiparameter .NET methods show up in F# as methods with tupled parameters:

```
let result = FruitFactory.GiveMe(2, "Apples")
```

Comment: Yes, it works, thank you. I was hoping to execute the function like `FruitFactory.GiveMe 2 "Apples"`. Is that possible to achieve?